# how to do multiple search in installed RPM packages?

Tags: linux, bash, package, redhat, sudo

how to do multiple search in installed RPM packages?

```
$ rpm -qa | grep 'mysql' 'jdk' 'jre'
```

or

```
$ rpm -qa | grep  mysql && rpm -qa | grep jdk && rpm -qa | grep jre
```

Comment: use -E options and | as separator like this `rpm -qa| grep -E "mysql|jdk|jre"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use egrep

```
    rpm -qa | egrep -i 'pattern|pattern2|patren3'
```

egrep can contain ~64Kb text

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of grep include the `-E` switch:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -Ei 'pattern|pattern2|patren3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below command to find multiple packages at once:

```
-rpm -qa |grep -e mysql -e jre -e jdk -i
```